# Browser not recognizing file

Tags: images, ftp, hosting

To start off I run Ubuntu 10.04 x64 with Windows XP SP3 in VirtualBox for Photoshop.

I created an image in Photoshop and saved it to a common NTFS partition (accessible to Ubuntu and WinXP). I used Filezilla (on Ubuntu) to upload the image to my web host (HostGator, CentOS server).

When I am browsing the server with Filezilla I can see the image I uploaded. I can download it and view it in multiple applications on Ubuntu and WinXP.

The funny thing is if I browse the file system with a browser (Firefox or IE) I get a 404 not found error. I set the directory to list contents and the image does not show in the browser when looking at the directory contents.

Could this be an encoding issue? Filezilla sees the file but the browser/server does not.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I have tried the following things

- CTRL+F5 to clear the browser cache.
- Viewing the page the image is on (doesn't show)
- Typing the direct URL to the images (gets 404)
- Setting the server to list folder contents (file is not listed)

**UPDATE 2:**

- I forgot to mention that I have created the file in PNG, JPEG, GIF (Photoshop Save for Web) and it hasn't made a difference. I think I am going crazy.

Comment: When using the browser, are you using `ftp://` or `http://` for the URLs?

Comment: when using direct url and browsing directory listing I am using http://

Comment: OK, try using `ftp://` instead, and see if that helps, FileZilla is an FTP client so it connecting to a different server process than the HTTP requests your browser is sending, so maybe it's a permissions issue on the server end.

Comment: I get 550 Can't change directory to /path/to/image.png: No such file or directory. It's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: How *odd*. So, to clarify, your web browser cannot see the file via direct URL or directory listing when using either HTTP or FTP. *But*, it's working correctly if you use the Filezilla FTP client?

Comment: @DMA I am going to give you the credit for solving this because you lead me to the error. It turns out to be an extreme case of stupidity on my part. When I setup the site I used a temp subdomain but when I launched it CPanel setup up a new directory with a copy of the old directory. I uploaded to the original directory but everything is now pointing to the new directory. Wow sorry!

Comment: +1 for taking ownership of your mistake by admitting it in an open forum.

Comment: @modern - I'm glad I help, even if it was somewhat indirectly. And you should post that as an answer and then (after the 2day time-limit) accept it, that way the question gets marked complete for the system and doesn't keep getting auto-bumped to the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DMA I am going to give you the credit for solving this because you lead me to the error. It turns out to be an extreme case of stupidity on my part. When I setup the site I used a temp subdomain but when I launched it CPanel setup up a new directory with a copy of the old directory. I uploaded to the original directory but everything is now pointing to the new directory. Wow sorry!